# modifying small part of an existing file

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I looked at boost's mapped_file, and CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile, but they seem overly complicated to use.

Anything simpler I can use to overwrite a few bytes here and there in an existing file?  Performance is not a very high consideration.

Comment: with files, security is also a non-functional specification one should be bothered about to decide on a suitable implementation

Comment: Are iostream, fstream etc failing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard C library directly. [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) then [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) to where you want to write stuff. Or, if you want to be fancy, you can also try [mmap](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested, and you should also check the HRESULTS error codes):

```
CAtlFile f;
f.Create( L"MyFile.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_ALWAYS );

CAtlFileMapping<BYTE> map;
map.MapFile( f , 0, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS );

printf( "%d bytes\n", (int)map.GetMappingSize() );

// Overwrite the 3-rd byte with 21
map[2] = 21;
```